# How to know register for I2C communication in pi

Tags: i2c

I want to communicate between raspberry pi 1 and a board with V850ES controller. To write/read to/from raspberry pi from/to the controller, I need to know the register address. How to find that? I  searched in data sheet but couldnt happen to find it. Kindly help.

Comment: Which version of the Pi are you using? Have you enabled I2C via raspi-config?

Comment: The SOC can only act as a master - not a slave.

Comment: Register address?  The register address of what?  The Pi or the V850?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the concern. I am using Raspberry pi 1 and done every configuration related to I2C till installing i2ctools. I want Register address of both pi and V850 as I want to read as well as write onto raspberry pi. Cant raspberry pi act as slave??

Comment: There is no workable solution known for making the Pi run as an I2C slave.  There is hardware support but no one has been able to create a workable driver in all the years since the Pi was launched.  You must assume the Pi runs as a master only.

Answer (score 0):

i am hopping your V850ES is a i2c slave device.
every i2c slave device has an address, so check if you can detect is or not.
if you don't have i2c tool installed .

do this

update your pi.

sudo apt-get update

upgrade to the latest os.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

make sure you also enabled i2c in your kernal. sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf then add a # on the 3rd line. sudo nano /etc/modules Add i2c-dev to a new line.

then try to install i2c tool.

sudo apt-get install i2c-tools

make sure your pi and sensor i2c voltage level are same. if you dont know how you can do that get a [pi shield](https://www.controleverything.com/products?f[0]=field_assigned_categories%3A6124&f[1]=field_assigned_categories%3A6619) like this.